# How to capture additional line from various worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I was given an old excel file with macro that copies scores and bservations from all the worksheets in that workbook into the first worksheet. The worksheets were amended with additional comments fields and I have tried to update the macro so it also shows it on the the first worksheet but to no avail. Here is the code:

```
sno = 1
lastcol = Sheets(1).Range("iv8").End(xlToLeft).Column


resrow = 9
headers = Array("Registration information", "CASE DETAILS (GENERAL) SCREEN", "Sender INFORMATION", "Client SCREEN", "PRODUCT", "Price")
For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
observ = ""
observno = 1
resrow = resrow + 1
rescol = 10
    lastrow = Sheets(i).Range("c65535").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets(1).Cells(resrow, 1) = sno
    Sheets(1).Cells(resrow, 2) = Sheets(i).Range("d2")
    Sheets(1).Cells(resrow, 4) = Sheets(i).Range("d9")
    Sheets(1).Cells(resrow, 3) = Sheets(i).Range("d3")
    Sheets(1).Cells(resrow, 5) = Sheets(i).Range("d4")
    Sheets(1).Cells(resrow, 6) = Sheets(i).Range("d5")
    Sheets(1).Cells(resrow, 7) = Sheets(i).Range("E9")


            While rescol <= lastcol - 4
            For j = 9 To lastrow
            If Sheets(i).Cells(j, 3) <> "" Then
             Sheets(1).Cells(resrow, rescol) = Sheets(i).Cells(j, 3)
             If Sheets(i).Cells(j, 3) > 0 And j <> lastrow Then
                observ = observ & observno & ". " & Sheets(i).Cells(j, 4) & vbCrLf

                observno = observno + 1

             End If
             rescol = rescol + 1
             End If
             Next j
            Wend

    Sheets(1).Cells(resrow, 8) = observ
    sno = sno + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

The new field in the worksheets is called comments and I tried to copy and amend this part

```
 While rescol <= lastcol - 4
            For j = 9 To lastrow
            If Sheets(i).Cells(j, 3) <> "" Then
             Sheets(1).Cells(resrow, rescol) = Sheets(i).Cells(j, 3)
             If Sheets(i).Cells(j, 3) > 0 And j <> lastrow Then
                commen = commen & commenno & ". " & Sheets(i).Cells(j, 4) & vbCrLf

                commenno = commenno + 1
```

But to no avail.

Here are the columns in the main worksheet (row 9 in worksheet)

[image]

Here is the example of the other worksheets[image]

Comment: Are the comments next to the observations i.e.  comments column is "E" ? Are there more than 1 comment fields ?

Comment: Yes, the comments are in column E and every row has a comment section. The macro above manages to capture all observations in main worksheet and puts sequential number next to it so if there is an observation in row 15, 18 and 19 it will put it into observation cell in main worksheet as 1. Obs 15, 2. Obs 18 3. Obs 19.

Comment: And you want them on Column I on the first sheet ?

Comment: I don't understand this line ;  If Sheets(i).Cells(j, 3) <> "" Then. What is in column C, is it a number and what has it to do with the observation in column D ?

Comment: Column A is sequential number, column B has fields that are being assessed, Column C has points (if field in column B has wrong entry a point is assigned in column C). Column D is an observation why the point was assigned.

Comment: So do you want all the comments regardless of any other column. Or don't you get a comment unless there is an observation, and you don't get observations unless there are points ? Maybe I will just post what I have and you can comment.

Comment: Comments are independent from points and observation. What I want is if the comments are present to put them all together in column I in the main worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar code for comments to that you have for observations.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Consolidate()

    Dim sno As Long, lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long, resrow As Long, rescol As Long
    Dim observno As Integer, commentno As Integer, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim observ As String, comment As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet

    Set wsRes = Sheets(1)
    sno = 1
    lastcol = wsRes.Range("iv8").End(xlToLeft).Column
    Debug.Print lastcol

    resrow = 9

    ' not sure what this is doing
    'headers = Array("Registration information", "CASE DETAILS (GENERAL) SCREEN", "Sender INFORMATION", "Client SCREEN", "PRODUCT", "Price")

    For i = 2 To Sheets.Count

        observ = ""
        comment = ""
        observno = 1
        commentno = 1
        resrow = resrow + 1
        rescol = 10

        ' determine last row by using Ctrl-Up from cell C1048576
        lastrow = Sheets(i).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set ws = Sheets(i)

        ' fill the current results columns1 to 6 from scorecard
        With wsRes.Cells(resrow, 1)
            .Offset(0, 0) = sno
            .Offset(0, 1) = ws.Range("D2")
            .Offset(0, 2) = ws.Range("D3")
            .Offset(0, 3) = ws.Range("D9")
            .Offset(0, 4) = ws.Range("D4")
            .Offset(0, 5) = ws.Range("D5")
            .Offset(0, 6) = ws.Range("E9")
            .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        End With

        ' scan down scorecard sheet starting at row 9 (probably should be 11)
        Dim qu As Integer
        For j = 9 To lastrow

            qu = rescol - 9

            ' skip the group heading between questions
            If Trim(Sheets(i).Cells(j, 3)) <> "" Then
                ' transfer score to result sheet
                ' move to next col ready for next Qu
                wsRes.Cells(resrow, rescol) = Sheets(i).Cells(j, 3)
                rescol = rescol + 1
            End If

            ' all observation regardless of score
            ' trim removes any hidden leading spaces
            ' if scan starts at 11 remove the And j > 9
            If Trim(ws.Cells(j, 4)) <> "" And j > 9 Then
                ' start new line for 2nd, 3rd etc observation
                If Len(observ) > 0 Then observ = observ & vbCrLf
                observ = observ & qu & ". " & ws.Cells(j, 4)
                'observno = observno + 1
            End If

            ' all comments regardless except first row which is header
            If Trim(ws.Cells(j, 5)) <> "" And j > 9 Then
                If Len(comment) > 0 Then comment = comment & vbCrLf
                comment = comment & qu & ". " & ws.Cells(j, 5)
                'commentno = commentno + 1
            End If

        Next j

        wsRes.Cells(resrow, 8) = observ
        wsRes.Cells(resrow, 9) = comment
        sno = sno + 1
    Next i
    MsgBox Sheets.Count - 1 & " sheets scanned", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It almost does what I want but I still have a minor issue. When I run it gives me a message for Headers - compile error variable not defined. In the original macro this message didn't come up. When I remove the line it run successfully but 2 things happen. Firstly, Column observations has always 1. in it even when there is nothing. 2ndly - All the scores from columns J further to the right dont match the number of columns with entries . If it is not clear I can post a excel screenshot. I assume this is what header was supposed to do - limit the columns

Comment: The only line before sno=1 is Sub consolidate()

Comment: Hello. I removed ' and then I got an error message. When I tried to remove the line headers completely it worked but the points in the main worksheet were copied few columns too far to the right.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you. One question though. Is there any way to capture the Observations only if there are any (not related to the score)? Also I changed rescol to 11 as it wasn't capturing all scores. And last but not least, if you have a moment can I kindly ask you to explain the code for me? I am newbie but I am trying to learn. I understand some bits but others are quite unclear for me. Once again thank you for your help.

Comment: @Cat Which score wasn't it capturing because from your screenshot Qu1 is in column 10 unless S.no is not column 1 . Something else that is odd and maybe because the sheet has been changed since the macro was written is the scan down starts at row 9 (which is a header ) whereas Qu1 is in row 11 ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was using wrong scorecard. It works fine now. In regards to my question about the observations regardless of points, I assume I need to amend the code with statement similar to the one re comments?

Comment: Actually I was thinking about that as well. If there is a way to do it that would be great.

Comment: Works nicely! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry for a blunt question but how do I amend the code to add a column in main sheet? What I mean is that I want to add a name of internal QC reviewer after column internal reviewer? I tried to change the code but then observations come up in MR name column.

Comment: @cat You probably need to increment the column on the two lines near the end to read wsRes.Cells(resrow, 9) = observ ,   wsRes.Cells(resrow, 10) = comment

Comment: Thank you for your help. When running the macro one of the excel files is causing runtime error 13. Data mismatch. When I debug it, it points to this bit of code ```If Trim(ws.Cells(j, 5)) <> "" And j > 9 Then```. When I remove the column with entries the macro works. What can cause the error?

Comment: @cat If you mean type mismatch, then try casting as string using CStr i.e.  If Trim(CStr(ws.Cells(1, 1))) <> "" Then. Check if any of the cells in that column have an error like #Name or #Ref or some other error.